# How to find the number of characters, vowels and lines in a file using java?

Tags: java

The program takes an input and then ask the user if he wants to input more. If yes, then the given input is stored in the next line.

The following code that I wrote shows zero for everything except number of characters.

Could someone please help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Ex_3 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("file4.txt");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("file4.txt");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter info in file:");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            fout.write(s.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter more data?");
            char c = sc2.next().charAt(0);
            if(c=='n')
            {
                break;
            }
            fout.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        }
        fout.close();
        int chars=0,vowels=0,lines=0,words=0;
        int i=0;
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
        {
            if((char)i!='\n'||(char)i!=' ')
            {
                chars++;
            }
            else if((char)i==' ')
            {
                words++;
            }
            else if((char)i+48=='a'||(char)i+48=='e'||(char)i+48=='i'|| 
            (char)i+48 =='o'||(char)i+48=='u')
            {
                vowels++;
            }
            else if((char)i=='\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of characters:"+chars);
        System.out.println("Number of vowels:"+vowels);
        System.out.println("Number of words:"+words);
        System.out.println("Number of lines:"+lines);
        fin.close();
        sc.close();
        sc2.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a debugger and placing a breakpoint on the second `while`. Then run the code step by step and observe what's going on with your if/else if blocks.

Comment: for vowels the check should be more `"AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1`

Comment: and yes, a debugger is the way to go - you have the code, you can do it

Comment: Note that you'd better use a single instance of `Scanner` , you don't need two .

Comment: Remove the `else` from `else if((char)i==' ')`. A char can be both a char and a vowel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed you code and made a few changes and comments. There were some mistakes in it.

```
//Use concrete imports! 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[])
{
//You only need one scanner
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try
{
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("file4.txt");
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("file4.txt");
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter info in file:");
        fout.write(sc.nextLine().getBytes());
        //sometimes the line break is not recognized from the shell
        fout.write('\n');

        System.out.println("Would you like to enter more data?");
        if( sc.nextLine().charAt(0) == 'n' ) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fout.close();
    sc.close();

    int chars=0,vowels=0,lines=0,words=2;
    int chars=0,vowels=0,lines=0,words=1;

    // With fin.read() you read 32 Bit integers from your input stream, 
    // which means that you have 4 chars "boxed" in one integer.
    int sizeOfStaticArray = 1024;
    //(ugly solution btw)
    byte[] arr = new byte[sizeOfStaticArray];
    fin.read(arr);
    byte i;
    for( int j = 0; j < sizeOfStaticArray; j++)
    {   
        i = (byte)arr[j];

        if(i == 0)
            break; 

        //You don't need casts to char 
        if( i != '\n' && i != ' ')
        {
            chars++;
        }
        //not else if. This is the main issue
        if( i == ' ' )
        {
            words++;
        }
        else if(i == 'a'||i  =='e'|| i == 'i'||  i =='o' || i == 'u')
        {
            vowels++;
        }
        else if( i == '\n' )
        {
            lines++;
            //increment word because the start of a line has no space
            words++;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    System.out.println("Number of characters:"+chars);
    System.out.println("Number of vowels:"+vowels);
    System.out.println("Number of words:"+words);
    System.out.println("Number of lines:"+lines);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

IO:

```
Enter info in file:
 aaaaa hhhhh zzzzz eeeee
Would you like to enter more data?
 y
Enter info in file:
 uuuuu ggggg ggggg iiiii
Would you like to enter more data?
 n
 Number of characters:40
 Number of vowels:20
 Number of words:8
 Number of lines:2
```

Hope that helps,
Good Luck!